# How to add if-else control inside convert command?

Tags: imagemagick

I have a script in `ImageMagick 7.0.10-61/Cygwin` like below one that crops some regions from a main image and merges in defined way.

```
for ((i=0; i<$num; i++)); do
    val=300
    
    if [[ $val -gt 300 ]]; then 
        convert "$input_image" +repage -write mpr:img -delete 0--1 -background none \
                \( \( -size 1600x120! xc:"#00377B" -fill white -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 90 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "${coords[0]}" \) \) \
                \( \
                    \( -size 426x50 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 42 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "TITLE A"  \) \
                    \( -size 426x50 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 42 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "TITLE B"   \) \
                    +smush +440 \
                \) \
                -smush +60 +gravity \
                \( \
                    \( -size 898x437! mpr:img -crop "${coords[1]}" +repage \( -size 70x50 xc:white \) -geometry +851+0 -composite -bordercolor "#4B8DF8" -border 2x2 \) \
                    \( -size 898x437! mpr:img -crop "${coords[2]}" +repage \( -size 70x50 xc:white \) -geometry +851+0 -composite -bordercolor "#4B8DF8" -border 2x2 \) \
                    +smush +12 -resize 1780x441! 
                \) \
                -gravity center -smush +10  \
                output_image$i.png
    else
        convert "$input_image" +repage -write mpr:img -delete 0--1 -background none \
                \( \( -size 1600x120! xc:"#00377B" -fill white -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 90 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "${coords[0]}" \) \) \
                \( \
                    \( -size 426x50 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 42 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "TITLE A"  \) \
                    \( -size 426x50 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 42 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "TITLE B"   \) \
                    +smush +440 \
                \) \
                -smush +60 +gravity \
                \( \
                    \( -size 898x437! mpr:img -crop "${coords[1]}" +repage \( -size 30x40 xc:white \) -geometry +840+0 -composite -bordercolor "#4B8DF8" -border 2x2 \) \
                    \( -size 898x437! mpr:img -crop "${coords[2]}" +repage \( -size 30x40 xc:white \) -geometry +840+0 -composite -bordercolor "#4B8DF8" -border 2x2 \) \
                    +smush +12 -resize 1780x441! 
                \) \
                -gravity center -smush +10  \
                output_image$i.png   
    fi
done
```

The scripts inside `if` and `else` are the same except for this block

```
\( \
    \( -size 898x437! mpr:img -crop "${coords[1]}" +repage \( -size 70x50 xc:white \) -geometry +851+0 -composite -bordercolor "#4B8DF8" -border 2x2 \) \
    \( -size 898x437! mpr:img -crop "${coords[2]}" +repage \( -size 70x50 xc:white \) -geometry +851+0 -composite -bordercolor "#4B8DF8" -border 2x2 \) \
    +smush +12 -resize 1780x441! 
\) \
```

if `$val > 300` then makes this composite

```
\( -size 70x50 xc:white \) -geometry +851+0
```

else makes this composite

```
\( -size 30x40 xc:white \) -geometry +840+0
```

Is there a way to include an `if-else` control inside the convert command in order to simplify the script? Something like this (below attempt doesn't work):

```
for ((i=0; i<$num; i++)); do
    val=300
    
        convert "$input_image" +repage -write mpr:img -delete 0--1 -background none \
                \( \( -size 1600x120! xc:"#00377B" -fill white -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 90 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "${coords[0]}" \) \) \
                \( \
                    \( -size 426x50 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 42 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "TITLE A"  \) \
                    \( -size 426x50 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 42 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "TITLE B"   \) \
                    +smush +440 \
                \) \
                -smush +60 +gravity \
                if [[ $val -gt 300 ]]; then  # BEGIN OF IF BLOCK
                    \( \
                        \( -size 898x437! mpr:img -crop "${coords[1]}" +repage \( -size 70x50 xc:white \) -geometry +851+0 -composite -bordercolor "#4B8DF8" -border 2x2 \) \
                        \( -size 898x437! mpr:img -crop "${coords[2]}" +repage \( -size 70x50 xc:white \) -geometry +851+0 -composite -bordercolor "#4B8DF8" -border 2x2 \) \
                        +smush +12 -resize 1780x441! 
                    \) \
                else   # ELSE BLOCK
                    \( \
                        \( -size 898x437! mpr:img -crop "${coords[1]}" +repage \( -size 30x40 xc:white \) -geometry +840+0 -composite -bordercolor "#4B8DF8" -border 2x2 \) \
                        \( -size 898x437! mpr:img -crop "${coords[2]}" +repage \( -size 30x40 xc:white \) -geometry +840+0 -composite -bordercolor "#4B8DF8" -border 2x2 \) \
                        +smush +12 -resize 1780x441! 
                    \) \                
                fi
                -gravity center -smush +10  \
                output_image$i.png
    else
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want, you can do that in Imagemagick by creating if/else for a variable before your convert command and then using that variable in the Imagemagick command.  For example

```
if [[ $val -gt 300 ]]; then
dims="70x50"
wd=851
else
dims="30x40"
wd=840
fi
```

Now, replace your command

```
for ((i=0; i<$num; i++)); do
    val=300
    
    if [[ $val -gt 300 ]]; then 
        convert "$input_image" +repage -write mpr:img -delete 0--1 -background none \
                \( \( -size 1600x120! xc:"#00377B" -fill white -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 90 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "${coords[0]}" \) \) \
                \( \
                    \( -size 426x50 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 42 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "TITLE A"  \) \
                    \( -size 426x50 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 42 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "TITLE B"   \) \
                    +smush +440 \
                \) \
                -smush +60 +gravity \
                \( \
                    \( -size 898x437! mpr:img -crop "${coords[1]}" +repage \( -size 70x50 xc:white \) -geometry +851+0 -composite -bordercolor "#4B8DF8" -border 2x2 \) \
                    \( -size 898x437! mpr:img -crop "${coords[2]}" +repage \( -size 70x50 xc:white \) -geometry +851+0 -composite -bordercolor "#4B8DF8" -border 2x2 \) \
                    +smush +12 -resize 1780x441! 
                \) \
                -gravity center -smush +10  \
                output_image$i.png
    else
        convert "$input_image" +repage -write mpr:img -delete 0--1 -background none \
                \( \( -size 1600x120! xc:"#00377B" -fill white -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 90 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "${coords[0]}" \) \) \
                \( \
                    \( -size 426x50 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 42 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "TITLE A"  \) \
                    \( -size 426x50 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 42 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "TITLE B"   \) \
                    +smush +440 \
                \) \
                -smush +60 +gravity \
                \( \
                    \( -size 898x437! mpr:img -crop "${coords[1]}" +repage \( -size 30x40 xc:white \) -geometry +840+0 -composite -bordercolor "#4B8DF8" -border 2x2 \) \
                    \( -size 898x437! mpr:img -crop "${coords[2]}" +repage \( -size 30x40 xc:white \) -geometry +840+0 -composite -bordercolor "#4B8DF8" -border 2x2 \) \
                    +smush +12 -resize 1780x441! 
                \) \
                -gravity center -smush +10  \
                output_image$i.png   
    fi
done
```

with

```
if [[ $val -gt 300 ]]; then
dims="70x50"
wd=851
else
dims="30x40"
wd=840
fi
for ((i=0; i<$num; i++)); do
    val=300
    
        convert "$input_image" +repage -write mpr:img -delete 0--1 -background none \
                \( \( -size 1600x120! xc:"#00377B" -fill white -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 90 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "${coords[0]}" \) \) \
                \( \
                    \( -size 426x50 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 42 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "TITLE A"  \) \
                    \( -size 426x50 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 42 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "TITLE B"   \) \
                    +smush +440 \
                \) \
                -smush +60 +gravity \
                \( \
                    \( -size ${dims}! mpr:img -crop "${coords[1]}" +repage \( -size 30x40 xc:white \) -geometry +${wd}+0 -composite -bordercolor "#4B8DF8" -border 2x2 \) \
                    \( -size ${dims}! mpr:img -crop "${coords[2]}" +repage \( -size 30x40 xc:white \) -geometry +${wd}+0 -composite -bordercolor "#4B8DF8" -border 2x2 \) \
                    +smush +12 -resize 1780x441! 
                \) \
                -gravity center -smush +10  \
                output_image$i.png   
    fi
done
```

Comment: Nice, that was the way I was looking for. Thanks again Fred!

Answer (score 1):

what if you construct the convert command dynamically like this:

```
for ((i=0; i<$num; i++)); do
    val=300
    
    # Conditional part of the command
    if [[ $val -gt 300 ]]; then
        conditional_part="\
            \( -size 898x437! mpr:img -crop \"${coords[1]}\" +repage \( -size 70x50 xc:white \) -geometry +851+0 -composite -bordercolor \"#4B8DF8\" -border 2x2 \) \
            \( -size 898x437! mpr:img -crop \"${coords[2]}\" +repage \( -size 70x50 xc:white \) -geometry +851+0 -composite -bordercolor \"#4B8DF8\" -border 2x2 \) \
            +smush +12 -resize 1780x441! \
        "
    else
        conditional_part="\
            \( -size 898x437! mpr:img -crop \"${coords[1]}\" +repage \( -size 30x40 xc:white \) -geometry +840+0 -composite -bordercolor \"#4B8DF8\" -border 2x2 \) \
            \( -size 898x437! mpr:img -crop \"${coords[2]}\" +repage \( -size 30x40 xc:white \) -geometry +840+0 -composite -bordercolor \"#4B8DF8\" -border 2x2 \) \
            +smush +12 -resize 1780x441! \
        "
    fi

    # Full command with the conditional part included
    convert "$input_image" +repage -write mpr:img -delete 0--1 -background none \
            \( \( -size 1600x120! xc:"#00377B" -fill white -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 90 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "${coords[0]}" \) \) \
            \( \
                \( -size 426x50 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 42 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "TITLE A"  \) \
                \( -size 426x50 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 42 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "TITLE B"   \) \
                +smush +440 \
            \) \
            -smush +60 +gravity \
            $conditional_part \
            -gravity center -smush +10  \
            "output_image$i.png"
done
```

Comment: thanks for your approach, I think could help me in other situations.